# .NET MVC how to get URL of embedded resource from another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

I am trying to get the URL of some resources I embedded in a class library I made.  There is one javascript and one css resource.  I need to be able to add these to specific razor views so that is where I'd like to access them.  If I can just get the correct URL for these resources then I should be fine.

I'm using MVC .Net Framework 4.5.2

**What I've Tried**

***1***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Default.Namespace.javascript.jsFile.js"></script>
```

result:

Unable to find file at the specified location `http://localhost:12345/Default.Namespace.javascript.jsFile.js`

***2***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@new FileStreamResult(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Defalut.Namespace.javascript.jsFile.js"), "text/javascript")"></script>
```

result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you are trying to do something that is not possible. Embedded resources has no path. It is **EMBEDDED** into an assembly.

**Option 1:**

You may want to create new Controller and handle distribution of embedded resources there.

```
public class ResourceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Css([Required]string filename)
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Defalut.Namespace.javascript." + filename), "text/javascript");
    }

    public ActionResult Js([Required]string filename)
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Defalut.Namespace.css." + filename), "text/css");
    }
}
```

And reference controller action(s).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("Js","Resource", new { filename = "jsFile.js" })"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Action("Css","Resource", new { filename = "cssFile.css" })">
```

You may want to deal with disposing stream instance and possible states inside the controller action. Embedded resource not found for example. Also you can cache results with `OutputCache` attribute to speed things up.

**Option 2:**

During the web app startup read embedded resources and save them to folder inside web app, then reference it.

**Related links:**

[OutputCacheAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thanks